# Definition of piecewise linear triangulation?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplex

I find it's definition in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)#Piecewise_linear_structures). But it is not self-contained (PL-sphere is not defined there) and does not list reference.

I am wondering is there any reliable reference giving the definition of PL-triangulation? (Some properties of it would be even better.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple definition of a PL triangulation of a manifold, by induction on dimension.

For the basis step, any triangulation of a 1-manifold is PL. In particular, every triangulated circle is PL.

Proceeding by induction, assuming that PL triangulations have been defined in dimension $n-1$, a triangulation of an $n$ dimensional manifold $M$ is PL if and only if for every vertex $v$ of $M$, the link of $v$ in $M$ is a PL triangulation of an $n-1$ dimensional sphere (the link of $v$ being the union of all simplices $\sigma$ such that $v \not\in \sigma$ and such that there exists a simplex $\tau$ such that $v \in \sigma \subset \tau$).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give any reference (textbook, lecture notes,...) of this definition?

Comment: And I think the link of $v$ is the collection of all simplices ..., not the union.

Comment: The point is that the link, like the union of any colleciton of simplices, is a subcomplex of the given simplicial complex structure on $M$.

Comment: For references take a look at [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96069/status-of-pl-topology); the first reference given there is the [Rourke-Sanderson book] I read oh so long ago.

Comment: I feel confused about this definition: consider a triangle xyz, which is a 2-simplex and homeomorphic to B^2. Let v be its barycenter. Then I feel the triangulation {xyv, xzv, yzv,...} should naturally be PL? But the link of x is yzv, which is not a triangulation of S^1?

Comment: Since your post did not mention what kinds of underlying topological spaces you were considering, I took the liberty of writing my answer about manifolds. Your latest example is a manifold-with-boundary, not a manifold; nontheless it's not hard to extend the definition of piecewise linear triangulation to manifolds-with-boundary.

Comment: I see. I find this PL triangulation concept in a combinatorial way, most of the simplicial complexes I consider are actually polyhedra (geometric simplicial complexes), and most topological spaces I consider are Euclidean spaces. At this point, it's good for me to find a definition of PL triangulation that works for $B^k$ and $S^k$.

Comment: For manifolds with boundary, you would add the inductive requirement that the link of a point on the boundary is a PL $B^k$ of one dimension lower.

Comment: So in your 2-simplex example, the link of a boundary vertex is a PL $B^1$ (as part of the basis step, all triangulations of $B^1$ are PL).